# FindOne function not working with Postgres

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

company.service.ts:`

```
async get(id: FindOneOptions<Company>): Promise<Company | null>{    
console.log(id)
return await this.companyRespository.findOne(id);
}
```

company.controller.ts:

```
@Get(':id')
  findOneCompany(@Param('id') id: FindOneOptions<Company>){
    return this.companyService.get(id);
 }
```

I have written the following code but whenever I try to get by FindOne my console says that "You must provide selection conditions in order to find a single row.".
I tried all possible solution on the web including adding curly braces and also using other FindOptions nothing seems to make this error go away.
My API platform shows an internal server error.

Comment: What is the code of the CompanyRepository.findOne method ?

Answer (score 4):

If it's an id I don't know why it's type is an interface. I think that's why you have vscode telling you that's an error. You should as @DinuMinhea says:

service.ts

```
async get(id: string | number): Promise<Company | null>{    
console.log(id)
return await this.companyRespository.findOne({where: {id}});
}
```

company.controller.ts:

```
@Get(':id') findOneCompany(@Param('id') id: string | number){ 
    return this.companyService.get(id); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the Entity field that you're searching by. In your case this is the `id`.

*company.service.ts*

```
...
async get(id: string | number): Promise<Company | null>{    
    console.log(id)
    return await this.companyRespository.findOne({ id });
}
```

Comment: vs code shows a red line under id when i do this. This is what it says:  Argument of type '{ id: FindOneOptions<Company>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOneOptions<Company>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'FindOneOptions<Company>'.

Comment: try this then:
findOne({ where: { id }});

Answer (score 0):

```
async get(id: FindOneOptions<Company>): Promise<Company | null>{    
console.log(id)
return await this.companyRespository.findOne({id: id});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `findByOne` rather than `findOne`, since `findOne` expects parameters such as `id`